# HDF5 Store string attributes with different sizes

Tags: c++, hdf5

- language: c++
- package: HDF5, version 1.6.8

I am currently using the following code to store an real array as an the attribute:

```
oid storeStringAttribute(H5::H5Location& group, string name, vector<double>& array)
{
    hsize_t dims[1];
    dims[0] = array.size();

    H5::DataSpace dataspace = H5::DataSpace(1, dims);
    H5::Attribute attribute = group.createAttribute(name.c_str(), NATIVE_DOUBLE, dataspace);
    attribute.write(H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE, vec.data());
}
```

I want to write a similar code to store a `vector<string>` array. **Is there an easy way to store the string array with variable size?**

What I'm currently doing is to use the larger size, but this is not very efficient.

```
void storeStringAttribute(H5::H5Location& group, string name, vector<string>& array)
{
    hsize_t dims[1];
    dims[0] = array.size();

    size_t maxStringSize = 0;
    for(size_t i=0; i<array.size(); i++)
    { maxStringSize = std::max(maxStringSize, array.size()); }

    H5::StrType strdatatype(H5::PredType::C_S1, maxStringSize+1);

    H5::DataSpace dataspace = H5::DataSpace(1, dims);
    H5::Attribute attribute = group.createAttribute(name.c_str(), strdatatype, dataspace);
    attribute.write(strdatatype, vec.data());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the answer:**

```
void storeStringAttribute(H5::H5Location& group, string name, vector<string>& array)
{
    hsize_t dims[1];
    dims[0] = array.size();

    H5::StrType strdatatype(H5::PredType::C_S1, maxStringSize+1);
    strdatatype.setSize(H5T_VARIABLE);

    H5::DataSpace dataspace = H5::DataSpace(1, dims);
    H5::Attribute attribute = group.createAttribute(name.c_str(), strdatatype, dataspace);
    attribute.write(strdatatype, vec.data());
}
```